# Calculating Percentage change over Month Correctly in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hello Lovely People of SO,

I am trying to calculate the percentage change over period of one MONTH of the subtotal of defective items in my dataset which looks like this:

| Date | ID_REG |
| --- | --- |
| 1/05/2002 | 2190 |
| 11/05/2002 | 13256 |
| 21/05/2002 | 23325 |
| 21/05/2002 | 12204 |
| 21/05/2002 | 28598 |
| 21/05/2002 | 14825 |
| 31/05/2002 | 40453 |
| 10/06/2002 | 26199 |
| 10/06/2002 | 31255 |
| 20/06/2002 | 4799 |
| 20/06/2002 | 25757 |
| 20/06/2002 | 44350 |
| 20/06/2002 | 8153 |
| 20/06/2002 | 45809 |
| 20/06/2002 | 51781 |
| 30/06/2002 | 14604 |
| 30/06/2002 | 12473 |
| 10/07/2002 | 12987 |
| 20/07/2002 | 11019 |
| 30/07/2002 | 15352 |
| 9/08/2002 | 50943 |
| 19/08/2002 | 41942 |
| 29/08/2002 | 5207 |
| 8/09/2002 | 188 |
| 8/09/2002 | 38890 |
| 8/09/2002 | 33634 |
| 18/09/2002 | 25477 |
| 18/09/2002 | 4941 |
| 28/09/2002 | 40831 |
| 28/09/2002 | 27395 |
| 37527 | 41821 |

each record of ID_REG represents the SERIAL_NUMBER of a product that was deemed defective and I need to calculate the change in percentage of defective products for instance In May 2002 there were only 7 defective products in total and in April 2022 there were 10, this means a difference of 100*(10-7)/7

in order to calculate this measure Im using the following DAX:

```
P_CHANGE_MONTH = 

    VAR __PREV_MONTH =
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTA('Sheet1'[ID_REG]),
            DATEADD('Sheet1'[Date].[Date], -1, MONTH)
        )
    RETURN
        DIVIDE(COUNTA('Sheet1'[ID_REG]) - __PREV_MONTH, __PREV_MONTH)
```

But I always get 0.0% no matter what I do, I always get 0.0% I have tried changing the date format and even the number of periods but it does not seem to work, look:

[image]

I wishing to be able to get a table like this one:

| Month | Subtotal | Delta % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 7 | 0,0% |
| 6 | 10 | 42,9% |
| 7 | 3 | -70,0% |
| 8 | 3 | 0,0% |
| 9 | 8 | 166,7% |

I will be so thankful if you guys can lead me in the right direction I have read so many post on the PBI forum but those solutions never seem to work on my dataset I will be super attentive to response to a lot your comments thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Power Query (`Home=>Transform Data=>Home=>Advanced Editor`)

If your query that returns the above table is named `Table`, then add a blank query and pasted this M code in place of the code in the window that appears when you select `Advanced Editor`:

```
let
    Source = Table,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "YearMonth", each Date.ToText([Date],"yyyyMM"), type text),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"YearMonth"}, {{"Defects", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Shifted Count" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Grouped Rows") & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Grouped Rows"[Defects],1)},
        type table[YearMonth=Text.Type, Defects=Int64.Type, Shifted Defects=Int64.Type]
    ),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Shifted Count", "perCent Change", each ([Defects]-[Shifted Defects])/[Shifted Defects], Percentage.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Shifted Defects"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

- Create a column with only the YearMonth (yyyyMM)

  - I included the year in case your data spanned multiple years and you want to separate the values that way.  If not, just format as `MM`
- Aggregate by Count (= Defects)
- Add a shifted column to the table
- Add a custom column with the percent change calculation

[image]

You can also do this with DAX

- Create a new table from your original data table
- Add a "first of the month" column
- Access the previous months value by using LOOKUPVALUE function along with DATEADD referring to the previous month.

***New Table***

```
Table 2 = 
    GROUPBY(
        ADDCOLUMNS('Table',"StartOfMonth", 1+EOMONTH('Table'[Date],-1)),
        [StartOfMonth],
        "Defects",
        COUNTAX(CURRENTGROUP(),"StartOfMonth"))
```

***Add the Percent Change Column***

```
Percent Change = 
    VAR prev = LOOKUPVALUE('Table 2'[Defects],'Table 2'[StartOfMonth], DATEADD('Table 2'[StartOfMonth],-1,MONTH))
RETURN
    ([Defects]-prev)/prev
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ron for your time I have tried to work this code:  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "YearMonth", each Date.ToText([Date],"yyyyMM"), type text), but I get the rror that Date cant be found and when I try to use the DAX approach  i get a gray experssion when I write: RETURN
    ([Defects]-prev)/prev as though PBI cant find this meassure

Comment: @R_Student As you can see from my screenshot, it clearly works here. Perhaps you did something different?  If you select the first line in my code `Source=`, what do you see?

Comment: Ron I had an issue in my original data the formatting of my Date col was different I was able to get it fixed then your M Code worked perfectly 10/10! thank you so much

Comment: Hej @RonRosenfeld, could you please help me with the my issue. I need you `M` expertise )  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73445353/record-to-a-text-variable/73445692?noredirect=1#comment129702659_73445692  . Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Mik It appears you have accepted an answer. May I assume your issue is resolved?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you very much for your response. David proposed acceptable solution, and I was little bit in hurry. But I would be glad if I could ask for help from you as one of the top SO experts. And sorry for disturbing. And thank you once again.