# Generate Calendar Table from Min/Max Seed

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to create a calendar from YYYYMM (Integer) value in my SQL table. Here is the first step - getting the start value = "01 jan 2019" in a Date format. The code below returns an error with a description that it "cannot convert a value of type Record to type Text".

```
let
mySource=
   Sql.Database("sqlServer"
      ,"DWH"
      ,[Query=
         "SELECT 
               MIN(mdate) as mdate 
            FROM BD_plan_AC 
          UNION 
          SELECT 
            MAX(mdate) as mdate 
         FROM myTable"
      ] 
 )-- here I get the mdate range within I want to build my calendar.
  -- from the first day of mdate to the end of the last mdate. 

,startDateAsNum=Record.Field(Table.First (mySource),"mdate")*100+1 
 // Table.First (mySource),"mdate")=201901
 // startDateAsNum=20190101
,startDateAsText=Text.From(startDateAsNum)
,startDateAsDate=Date.FromText(startDateAsText,[Format="yyyyMMdd"])
in
startDateAsDate
```

Many thanks in advance.

---

The idea is to get the mdate range and build a calendar from the first day of min to the last day of max, so, all dates from the range are in.

mySource = -- dates are not constant and comes from the query.

| mdate |
| --- |
| 201901 |
| 202212 |

This, what I want to get finally - a calendar with a Date() data type. (Dates are as dd.mm.yyyy)

| Date |
| --- |
| 01.01.2019 |
| 02.01.2019 |
| .... |
| 31.12.2022 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input data, you can generate a calendar as follows.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwtDQwVIrVATGNjAyNlGJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [mdate = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"mdate", type text}}),
    start = #date( Number.From( Text.Range( #"Changed Type"[mdate]{0},0,4 )) ,Number.From( Text.Range( #"Changed Type"[mdate]{0},4,2 )),1 ),
    end = #date( Number.From( Text.Range( #"Changed Type"[mdate]{1},0,4 )) ,Number.From( Text.Range( #"Changed Type"[mdate]{1},4,2 )),31 ),
    cal = { Number.From( start ) .. Number.From( end ) },
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(cal, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Comment: This is it! ) Billion thanks, @David!!! and long life )

Answer (score 1):

try this to get the data from SQL in Format yyyymmdd then maybe you have to convert anything...

```
SELECT 
              format(cast(MIN(mdate) ,datetime),"YYYYMM") as mdate 
            FROM BD_plan_AC 
          UNION 
          SELECT 
            format(cast(MAX(mdate) ,datetime),"YYYYMM")  as mdate 
         FROM myTable
```

Comment: HI Umut, thank you for the idea. In general it would be easer to get the date and CALENDER in DAX then in SQL, but I'm trying to get an experience with M.

Comment: @Mik hi again. it is always better to import the data from source as useful as it can be... )))

Comment: That's for sure. But my "Bushido" is M ). and mdate is a number.

Comment: something like ...

Source = {Number.From(min(mdate)) .. Number.From(max(mdate))}

Comment: first = #date(
          Number.From(List.Min(mdate))
          ,1,1 )

Comment: @Mik these hints will help you ;)

Comment: @Mik any time bratan )))

Comment: first = #date( Number.From(List.Min(Text.Start(mdate,4))) ,Text.Middle(mdate,5,2),1 )

Comment: @Mik  I gave all clues and David got the badge ))) I thought you wanted to learn how to catch a fish, not eating the fish directly )))

Comment: Hi Umut, you helped me a lot, and I'm very thankful for your hints, especially for the last. Thank to exactly your hints I solved the issue with in a different to Davids solution way - more math and less M. As for the badge, David is the one who answered the question. And thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do anything?

**01 jan 2019** converts perfectly to a date with Date.From() in powerquery

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I also want to get a max date that is not a constant. So I'm interested in how to get a text from a number and get date from text, or get dynamical date from number that I receive from a query.

Comment: Provide sample format of your input, and desired output

Comment: I added, please, look.

Comment: Why would two of your items convert to the first day of the month, and the other one converts to the last day of the month?  There needs to be some consistency in what you want your output to be

Comment: My idea is to get the mdate range and build a calendar from the first day of min to the last day of max, so, all dates from the range are in.